# How can we have recurring related fields on custom report?

Tags: civireport, contributions, recurring-contributions

I want recurring related fields on the custom report, but there is only one field available as per the civicrm i.e. **Recurring contribution ID**.

The fields that I was looking for are **Recurring Units**, **Recurring Intervals**, **Offer Installments**. I am quite unsure if there is some configuration available on civicrm with which we can achieve this. Also please help if there is any API hooks that I can use it to make this happen.

[image]

Comment: Recurring contributions are stored as a seperate entity/SQL-table. The only link to the contribution entity/SQL-table is recurring contribution ID.

Comment: @Flying thank you for the informations, is there any hooks or api that can be used to extend this form and add extra recurring fields ?

Comment: Probably, but that is out of my reach...:-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using CiviCRM 4.6, there's now a CiviCRM report template that uses the recurring contribution table as a base and gives you access to a bunch of those related fields.

I've got a custom extension here: https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.contributionrecur
which backports that report to earlier CiviCRM versions, and also adds a few more fields.

I notice in your picture you are actually trying to export records, presumably to generate a report in a separate piece of software. You can do something similar from any (CiviCRM) report, i.e. it has a csv download option, and the ability to select which fields to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the recurring units and recurring interval from civicrm_contribution_recur table (looking at it in phpMyAdmin is likely easiest, or you can examine the code's xml schema definition at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/xml/schema/Contribute/ContributionRecur.xml#L61 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/xml/schema/Contribute/ContributionRecur.xml#L78.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'Offer installments' but if it is the installments paid so far, then you can retrieve all of the records in civicrm_contribution table where civicrm_contribution.contribution_recur_id = civicrm_contribution_recur.id (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/xml/schema/Contribute/Contribution.xml#L345).